# Are there any frameworks to develop chat applications in webapplications using java

Tags: jakarta-ee

Hi i would like to Develop Chat Application which i can be embeeded in my web applcation Developed using java and struts2,Are there any frameworks to develop chat applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop a chat application using exiting java technologies such as jms , http://oreilly.com/catalog/javmesser/chapter/ch02.html
However ,There is one framework named dwr-java http://www.packtpub.com/article/chatroom-application-using-dwr-java-framework which you can use as a demo chat application.
But I recommend  to use spring frameworks to develop such chat application,there are lots of demo application available ,just google it.

Answer (score 4):

To develop a chat application first you should decide what kind of chat you want to have, just text messaging or voice chat or video or all of them! Then you should choose a protocol for that. One of the most famous protocol for commuticative applications is [***xmpp***](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/). 
Having a chat application in your web application has two parts: Serverside and Clientside. There are a lot of free and opensource [***server***](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/) and [***client***](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) who support xmpp. To have a chat application it's better to use one of them.

I had some project like the one that you want and in that project I used [***Openfire***](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) as server and [***claros***](http://www.claros.org/web/showProduct.do?id=2) as web client. You don't need to do any work for server, but to have chat web client, you should use [***claros***](http://www.claros.org/web/showProduct.do?id=2) pages and libraries in your project. It's easy and doesn't need any special Java EE framework.